# TypeError when calculating an algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to create an algorithm in Python 2.7.9 which can be viewed below:

[image]

This equates to:

`10/3 (-510 + sqrt(15) * sqrt(-44879 + 1000 * y))`

When I try to solve it in python with the following code:

```
from __future__ import division
import math

y = 66

x = "%0.2f" % (10/3 (-510 + sqrt(15) * sqrt(-44879 + 1000 * y)))

print x
```

I receive the following error:

`TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Why is this? I have another algorithm below which works just fine:

```
x = "%0.2f" % (-5/4*(-463 + math.sqrt(1216881 - 16000 *y)))
```

Comment: `10/3 (` you forgot the `*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the multiplication operator below:

```
x = "%0.2f" % (10/3 (-510 + sqrt(15) * sqrt(-44879 + 1000 * y)))
                    ^ Need to add '*'
```

Comment: Wounded! What a spot, thanks very much, I have been scratching my head for ages! @JoelCornett

Comment: Also note that (I think they are using Python 2.x) they are multiplying by `10/3` which results in `3` (`int`)

Comment: @Cyber: Good to think about, but I think OP edited his question and added `from __future__ import division` at the top of his code.

Comment: I already had the `division` import in, I just edited the Python version `2.7.9`. @Cyber

Answer (score 2):

Where is the multiplication operator?

```
x = "%0.2f" % (10/3 * (-510 + sqrt(15) * sqrt(-44879 + 1000 * y)))
```

Tip

Whenever you get `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`, it means that you have something like an integer followed immediately by a brace. Check out for that, Debugging will be a piece of cake.